# PostgreSQL 9.3.5 'Active-Active' mode for Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: database, postgresql-9.3, database-cluster

I want 2 PostgreSQL Databases (running in Windows Server) to be on 'active-active' mode. Currently they are in 'Hot Standby Mode' (one of them is 'Master' and the other one is 'Slave'). I can't seem to find any documentation that has made high available PostgreSQL DBs on Windows. I am lost and know very little of how to approach.

A little help (say some tutorial, documentations etc) would be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) you should upgrade as soon as possible. But even with Postgres 12, you can't have an active-active cluster with Postgres. Why do you think you need that anyway? Having primary and a hot standby (that can be used for reads) **is** the way to provide high availability

Comment: It's what our Client wants apparently. Even if we tell them to upgrade to a latest version, would it be possible to configure 'Active-Active' mode on Windows Server?

Comment: As I wrote, not it's not possible. But if your client uses an unsupported Postgres version, they apparently don't really care for their data to begin with. You should at least upgrade to the latest 9.3 minor version [Upgrading from 9.3.5 to 9.3.25 gives you 4.3 years worth of fixes (599 of them)](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.3.5&to=9.3.25&keywords=)

Comment: I see. Thank you! You're a lifesaver. :D